# react component props does not have match

Tags: reactjs, react-router, match

I'm using react-routing-dom V5 in my react project.
I need to pass props from App component (where I import Router) to child component through protected route.
The problem is that props is empty, does not have match, location, history..

**App Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    console.log(this.props); //props does not have match propreties
    return (
    <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <React.Fragment>
            <Switch>
             <ProtectedRoute path='/exemple' component={Exemple}/>
             </Switch>
          </React.Fragment>
        </Router>
    );
 }
}
```

NOTE: I pass props from App to child component where i need to use this.props.match, but match is undefinded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`match` props is only available to components of a route:

```
<Route exact path="/foo" component={({ match }) => console.log(match)} />
```

If you need it on App, you need to create a route for App.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'

class App extends Component {
  render(){
    console.log(this.props); //props does not have match propreties
    return (
    <div className="App">
        <Router>
          <React.Fragment>
            <Switch>
<Route
  path='/dashboard'
  render={(props) => <Dashboard {...props} isAuthed={true} />}
/>
             </Switch>
          </React.Fragment>
        </Router>
    );
 }
}
```

Comment: Can please explain how can i pass props throught a protected route? i edited my question

Comment: props are accessible throughout your component try consoling them you can use constructor too. You need more specifications comment again I will update my code with another example

Answer (score 0):

of course, it shouldn't have  match object
A match object contains information about how a  matched the URL.
 way to access the match object from

```
Route component as this.props.match
Route render as `({ match }) => ()`

Route children as ({ match }) => ()

`withRouter` as this.props.match
```

Answer (score 0):

In a component that isn't routed you should use:

`import { useParams, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'`

`const history = useHistory()`

`const { keyword, id, whateverTheParamIs } = useParams()`